# connect: Network is unreachable? - ping

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns

When I attempt to ping google's dns or any outside the network I get 
`connect: Network is unreachable`?

I can't update either which I put down to this

I am new to networking... And Ubuntu. But these are results of some commands I thought might help

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:7f:a9:10:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.5/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::20e:7fff:fea9:1054/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 86:0b:cb:43:63:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
mcserver@helloworld:~$ 

$ vi /etc/resolv.conf:
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.0.5
nameserver 8.8.8.8

$ vi /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
        dns-nameservers 192.168.0.5 8.8.8.
```

Comment: What's the output of `ip route show`

Comment: 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.5 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1

Comment: `ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0` should get you connectivity, assuming your routers ip address is 192.168.0.1. If this works (try `ping 8.8.8.8` first, then google.com) check my answer for persisting the changes.

Comment: @user240010, You wrote an excellent solution. May I ask how you figured it out? Thanks.

Comment: @GnP,  You wrote an excellent and clever solution. I discovered just now that it does not persist after logout. Could you please tell me how to persist it? Thanks.

Comment: @Frank I'm not sure I understand the question. Network configuration isn't affected by login/logout except in very particular circumstances (nm+wifi maybe). The answer I posted below is a `/etc/network/interfaces` entry, which is persistent accross reboots.

Comment: @GnP, Thank you for your reply tonight. I tested the 1 answer below and it had no effect after logout and login. I really admired your ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 idea that it should get you connectivity, assuming your routers ip address is 192.168.0.1. . How might we make it persist?

Comment: @GnP, I made the mistake of editing my network connection to automatic DHCP which forces a renewal of DHCP lease after logout and relogin and destroys persistence across reboots. How could I fix that mistake on my part? Thank you.'

Comment: @Frank depends on what you did, what type of connection, etc. You should ask a new question, posting your current config and whatever else you find relevant.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/667800/476079

Comment: Finally, the below helped me resolve the issue
https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2018/10/dns-on-ubuntu-18.04/

Comment: route add default gw 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3  # OK

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following line is wrong:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< It should be 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.5 8.8.8.8
```

Also, there doesn't seem to be any default gateway setup.

Not having more info about your network, I would suggest adding the following line at the end:

```
    gateway <YOUR.ROUTER.IP.ADDRESS>
```

So, assuming your router ip address is 192.168.0.1, this would be the whole entry:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.5 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you need to set your default gateway

1. Take terminal
2. Type in

   ```
   sudo ip route add default via <your gateway>(eg:192.168.136.1) dev eth0
   ```
3. Sometimes you will be able to ping (`ping 8.8.8.8`) but no internet connection in the browser, then:
4. Go to `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`
5. Add `nameserver 8.8.8.8`
6. Add `nameserver <your gateway>` or `nameserver 127.0.1.1`
7. `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` or `sudo service networking restart`

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.  Two remarks: 1. Refrain answering questions with an accepted answer unless you really come with something different. 2. Never advise to `sudo su`, as this is considered bad practice here for many reasons.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to add a default gateway. As a root user, execute this command.

E.g.

```
root@localhost:~# route add default gw 172.23.5.1
```

You can get the first 3 octets, 172.23.5 from eth0/eoM

Then ping an IP to see if connection works.

```
root@localhost:~# ping 10.56.94.81    
PING 10.56.94.81 (10.56.94.81) 56(84) bytes of data.    
64 bytes from 10.56.94.81: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.203 ms    
64 bytes from 10.56.94.81: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.197 ms    
64 bytes from 10.56.94.81: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=0.210 ms    
^C    
--- 10.56.94.81 ping statistics ---    
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2033ms    
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.197/0.203/0.210/0.012 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if your system is behind a firewall, that can't interact with internet. Unless you specify a proxy server for HTTP/HTTPS/FTP, it is not reachable.

Try this:

```
export  http_proxy=http://yourcompanyproxy.company.com:1234   
export  ftp_proxy=ftp://yourcompanyproxy.company.com:1234  
export  https_proxy=https://yourcompanyproxy.company.com:1234
```