# Beaglebone black with Debian OS on Ubuntu 14.04 in Virtualbox VM

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, dns, debian, beagleboard

I am using the Beaglebone Black for the first time. It has the Debian 7.4 OS and I'm using Ubunbtu 14.04 installed in Virtualbox. I'm trying to install Python IO libraries but I'm getting the `Can't resolve host name` error. Pinging anything is giving the `connect: Network is unreachable` error. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Result of apt-get update and ping]

ifconfig:

[image: result of ifconfig]

sources.list and hosts:

[image: result of sources.list and hosts]

/etc/network/interfaces:

[image: /etc/network/interfaces]

where `192.168.1.1` is the IP address of my router and `192.168.0.1` is the IP address of my modem (ref: [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/415023/connect-network-is-unreachable-ping))

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
domain localdomain
search localdomain
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

`ip rout show`: `192.168.7.0/30 dev usb0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.7.2`

`yum` doesn't install because of `can't resolve ...` error (so no info on dig or nslookup)

/etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return]  mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

I am new to Ubuntu and this is all the info I thought I would need to provide. Please let me know if there is anything more.

Comment: What are the Virtual Box network settings for your virtual machine?

Comment: NAT. And I forgot to add that Ubuntu is doing fine with pinging and connecting to the internet

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you are connecting your BBB(Beaglebone Black) to the internet "eth0" card is provided with a dhcp client by default.

The "usb0" card is a virtual card that help you to connect your BBB to a PC with any OS, you can allways connect your BB to windows after installing drivers and you can simply use putty to reach the terminal of BBB, if your are sure about using Ubuntu you can install it into your PC or you should connect your BBB to the internet using Ethernet, also you can use any standard Wifi card to make BBB online.

I'll be glad for any help ThanKs.